# SQL: How many visits per weekday?

Tags: sql

I have a table like this one:

```
Visit,Visitdate;
A,2015-03-31T11:11:00.000+0000;
B,2015-03-31T12:11:00.000+0000;
C,2015-04-31T16:11:00.000+0000;
D,2015-07-31T16:15:00.000+0000;
C,2015-04-31T16:11:00.000+0000;
D,2015-07-31T16:15:00.000+0000;
```

...

I need to know the number of visits per weekday (Monday, Tuesday,...)

I tried with the following code but it does not work:

```
`SELECT date_format (Visitdate, 'EEEE') FROM table,
COUNT (*) AS VisitCount from table group by Visitdate`
```

With `SELECT date_format (Visitdate, 'EEEE') FROM table` I am able to specify the weekday.

With `SELECT Visitdate, COUNT (*) AS VisitCount from table group by Visitdate` I am able to count the number of visits per `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS`

However I am not able to combine both codes to make it work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
SELECT 
    date_format(Visitdate, 'EEEE'), COUNT(*) AS VisitCount
FROM table
GROUP BY date_format(Visitdate, 'EEEE')
```

This way you group by the names of the day and count the rows that match each day (by the group)

Comment: You are welcome :) Will appreciate also a vote-up on the answer when you have enough reputation for that :)

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there - you just need to group by the weekday (like you formatted it in the select list) instead of the date itself:

```
SELECT   DATE_FORMAT (Visitdate, 'EEEE'), COUNT (*) AS VisitCount
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT (Visitdate, 'EEEE')
```